# RealmResults size is returning Zero

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I have  a little problem, and I couldn't find any results. Yes I did some researches too.

I have a variable mResults = RealmResults < Drop > ;

and this has Data as you can see in the picture below

[image]

But when I type >>mResults.size<< it returns 0. 
What could the problem be? btw. Im working in Android using kotlin.

The pröblem is in the Recyclerview getItemCöunt

ActivityMain::::

```
Realm.init(this)
        val configuration = RealmConfiguration.Builder().build()
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration)
    mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
            val results:RealmResults<Drop> = mRealm.where(Drop::class.java).findAll()

            mToolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
            mRecycler = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_drops)
            val manager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

            mRecycler.layoutManager = manager
            mRecycler.adapter = AdapterDrops(this, results)
```

---

```
open class Drop : RealmObject {
private var what: String? = null
@PrimaryKey
private var added: Long? = null
private var whenT: Long? = null
private var completed: Boolean? = null

constructor(){}

constructor(what: String, added: Long, whenT: Long, completed: Boolean) : super() {
    this.what = what
    this.added = added
    this.whenT = whenT
    this.completed = completed
}


fun getWhat(): String? {
    return what
}

fun setWhat(what: String) {
    this.what = what
}


fun getAdded(): Long? {
    return added
}

fun setAdded(added: Long) {
    this.added = added
}

fun getWhenT(): Long? {
    return whenT
}

fun setWhenT(whenT: Long) {
    this.whenT = whenT
}


fun getCompleted(): Boolean? {
    return completed
}

fun setCompleted(completed: Boolean) {
    this.completed = completed
}
```

}

```
class AdapterDrops: RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDrops.DropHolder> {
    private var mInflater:LayoutInflater
    private var mResults:RealmResults<Drop>
    constructor(context:Context, results: RealmResults<Drop>){
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        mResults = results

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DropHolder?, position: Int) {
        val drop:Drop = mResults[position]!!
        holder!!.mTextWhat.setText(drop.getWhat())

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): DropHolder {
        val view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_drop, parent, false)
        val holder = DropHolder(view)
        return holder
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mResults.size   <<<<< pröblem
    }

    class DropHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        var mTextWhat:TextView
        constructor(itemView: View):super(itemView){
            mTextWhat = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_what)

        }

    }

}
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: please share some code

Comment: Ökay I did.. höpe sömeöne can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this as you are fetching all records from db

```
var mResults:OrderedRealmCollection<Drop> = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(Drop::class.java).findAll()
```

Please define Drop class with empty constructor.

Please remove below code from activity and paste them in your application class

```
  //region initialise Realm for application
    Realm.init(this)
    //endregion

    //region creating realm config
    val realmConfig:RealmConfiguration = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("kotlin_demo.realm")
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build()
    //endregion

    //region for development purpose getting new realm db each time
    Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig)

    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig)
    //endregion
```

in kotlin no need to define the getter setter methods for Drop class so remove that

Comment: Man, it wOrked with the OrderedRealmCOllectiön.. thanks a löt.. but can u tell me why? why the size in REalmresults is 0?

Comment: The result for you query is always appears as Collection of OrderedRealm objects, As the result has so many parameters out of which we get result in for mo OrderedRealmCollection not as normal list of object.

Comment: `Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(` that's not good, now you can never close the Realm instance

Comment: You can close your instance after transaction. i have created it as simple demo.